# How to use PHP session variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a .php file and .js file. I want to use the `php` variable in `javascript` file but its not working. I found a solution by using session but that didn't worked.Can anybody provide me a solution or have a look at the code if there is any mistake.

In .php

```
 $wd=500/$w;
 $_SESSION['wd']=$wd;
```

In .js

```
  var sf= <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['wd']);?>;
```

Comment: Try `var sf= '<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['wd']);?>';` Note quotes.

Comment: I tried adding quotes,but its not receiving any value,it shows blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass session value from php file to js by following method .

**php file :-**

```
 $wd=500/$w;
 $_SESSION['wd']=$wd;
 echo '<script>var pf = '.json_encode($_SESSION['wd']).';</script>';
```

**Js file :-**

```
 var sf = pf;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply pass the value through PHP like

```
 $wd=500/$w;
 $_SESSION['wd']=$wd;
 echo '<script>var passedData = '.json_encode($_SESSION['wd']).';</script>';
```

And catch the the data in javascript like as

```
 var sf = passedData;
```